# Embedding .pdf inside .swf

Tags: flash, pdf

I need a solution to embed a pdf inside a flash screen i.e. want to open a pdf file inside a flash screen without redirecting the pdf to a new browser.

Regards,

ASV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try this http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Comment: Thank you Auxi.. very kind of you to answer a stale question :) .. but believe we didn't find an answer to this until you answered...

Answer (score 0):

No, flash cannot load pdf files directly without converting those to images.

Comment: Thanks Mark, could you elaborate more on this??

Comment: I mean, you need a server side script that convert pdf to images and show those in PDF, I dont have any library in my hand now.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but a pdf viewer is not going to be available. Do you think there would some pdf to swf converters, which provide their SDK as well. In this case we could call the converter tools methods on the fly and convert a pdf to swf.

Comment: I don't see pdf to swf direct converter before friend. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Best is this solution: [FlipdooSDK | PDF to Flash SDK](http://www.conaito.com/products/flipdoo-sdk.aspx)  You get full developer sdk for converting and viewing with beautiful page flip